# where are the method return and parameters stored in memory in java

Tags: java, memory, methods, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have trouble understanding the return types of a method in java. Where is it supposed to be? On the stack or heap?
Let's take this example snippet:

```
/** the snippet returns the minimum between two numbers */
    public int minFunction(int n1, int n2) {
       int min;
       if (n1 > n2){
          min = n2;
       }else{
          min = n1;
          return min; 
          }
       }
```

how and where are minFunction, n1, n2, min stored in memory. if i call the method with the numbers 3 and 5 what will happen?

Comment: The actual method is stored in the [Method Area](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4). Parameters, return values, local variables,... are stored within a [Method Frame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4), which in return resides on the [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2).

Comment: "if i call the method with the numbers 3 and 5 what will happen?" - it will return 3 (after the code is updated so it compiles).

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 options

- You can store the returned value like this (for further uses)

  ```
  int minValue;
  minValue = minFunction(3,5)
  ```
- or you can directly show it using a System.out.print() command like this

  ```
  System.out.println("the minimum value between 3 and 5 is" + minFuction(3,5));
  ```

In both cases, the returned value will be 3.

It doesn't get "stored" anywhere per se, but you CAN store it or just show it.

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: "It doesnt get "stored" anywhere per se, but you CAN store it or just show it" - That is simply wrong. Even if you "just show" something, it has to be stored at some memory location to be shown. Your answer does in deed not answer the question. You should read up on heap- and stackmemory.

Comment: If it isn't stored anywhere it doesn't exist. Your answer doesn't even make sense.